# Select rows from two tables only whenn 'all in'

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've got the following tables

Table1

```
Col1 | Col2

r1c1 | r1c2

r2c1 | r2c2

r3c1 | r3c2

r4c1 | r4c2
```

Table2

```
Col1_Table1 | Col2

r1c1_table1 | r1c2

r2c1_table1 | r2c2

r3c1_table1 | r3c2
```

So you see my row #4 is missing in Table2.

Select all rows from table 1 and join table 2. No Problem

But what looks the select like when I want to select all from Table1 but only if all from Table1 are in Table2? I hope you can understand.
In my example I the result of the select has to be zero/null.

Comment: Are you just looking for INNER JOIN??

Comment: No in inner join I would receive my first three rows because they are in Table1 and Table2. But I want to have only a result if all rows from Table1 also are in Table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,  you want to return all rows of table 1 only if all of table 1 also exists in table 2

So in effect:

```
SELECT * FROM #table1
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #table1)
 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table1 INNER JOIN #Table2 ON #Table1.col1 = #Table2.col1)
```

Is that correct? in which case a better way of doing this would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM #table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM #table1
      WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM #table2)
);
```

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly. I will try your answers and will give you a feedback tomorrow

Comment: I could not wait and tested your solutions. I like the second one and it works for me. So thanks for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for INTERSECT.

Ex:

```
select Col1, Col2 from table1
INTERSECT
select Col1, Col2 from table2
```

Intersect will return results based on data being in BOTH tables.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see example below

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table2
END

CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    Col1 NVARCHAR(20)
    , Col2 NVARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('r1c1', 'r1c2')
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('r2c1', 'r2c2')
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('r3c1', 'r3c2')
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES ('r4c1', 'r4c2')

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    Col1_Table1 NVARCHAR(20)
    , Col2 NVARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES ('r1c1_table1','r1c2')
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES ('r2c1_table1','r2c2')
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES ('r3c1_table1','r3c2')

SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Result'
FROM #Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN #Table2 AS t2
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table1
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #Table2
END
```

Hope it helps